# Irregular elements in the python list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to modify my list of 2D lists, but as a result of the function, I got somewhat irregular elements.

For example, firstly I have defined my list of lists:

```
delta_x = [1,1]

x = [0,0]

okolina = [[x[0] + delta_x[0], x[1] + delta_x[1]], [x[0] + delta_x[0], x[1]],
                   [x[0] + delta_x[0], x[1] - delta_x[1]], [x[0], x[1] - delta_x[1]],
                   [x[0] - delta_x[0], x[1] - delta_x[1]], [x[0] - delta_x[0], x[1]],
                   [x[0] - delta_x[0], x[1] + delta_x[1]], [x[0], x[1] + delta_x[1]]]
```

I'm tryin to modify this list of 2D lists, so that every element that is lesser or greater than limit value, becomes equal to that value. For explanation, I'm creating space around one number in my implementation of Local search algorithm, and I want to check if all points of created space are inside predefined borders of environment.

So the function that I created for checking that condition is:

```
def checkRange(X, x1, x2):
    x = X 
    for i in range(0,len(X)):
        if x[i][0] < -x1:
            x[i][0] = -x1
        elif x[i][0] > x1:
            x[i][0] = x[1]
        elif x[i][1] < -x2:
            x[i][1] = -x2
        elif x[i][1] > x2:
            x[i][1] = x2
        else:
            continue
    return x
```

This function has 3 input values X-my space of dots, x1 is limit for the x axis, and x2 is the limit for the y axis.
Please ignore the fact that there are easier ways to check if elements of one list are inside predefined range, and probably fact that this isn't correct way of checking and modifying my elements. If i just look at this function, it's completely correct for me, I iterate through my list, compare first elements of every list with x1, and second elements with x2 and if there are irregularities I modify that element.

So the result of my implementation is this:

[image]

I really don't understand what elements like [[...], 0] represent in Python. I know that [...] is list inside of the list, but why do my code generate this for the first 3 elements of my list and last 5 elements are correctly modified?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: You've got an `x[1]` in that code that looks like it was supposed to be `x1`.  Also note that the `x = X` at the top is pointless - there's only one list here, with two names that refer to it.  You might as well have named the parameter `x` instead of `X`.  If the goal was to modify a copy of the list, then you need to explicitly make that copy - Python never does that automatically.

Comment: Ohhh God...I need to check again my dioptre. I will delete this q, because I'm embarrassed. Thank You very much Jason. I can see that `x=X` is pointless. I didn't know that modification on the argument are permanent. Thank You very much again,

Comment: Another thing, you should be careful on how to put your if conditions : if I understand well, you want to check the x values AND the y values. The way you're writing your condtions won't work because it would check the x axis conditions (the first 2 conditions and one of them is certainly satisfied, unless you have x[i][0]==x1) and thus, it will not resume the checking on the y values.You should use two different if statements

Comment: Yes You're right Mouna. If I have for example both elements that are incorrect in values, only one modification is done. Thank You very much.